# from where is nameserver 1.1.1.1 getting added to my ubuntu /etc/resolv.conf

Tags: networking, server, dns, systemd-resolved

I am running my own DNS server, which I have added to the router, every device on the networks gets the custom DNS, but my ubuntu server that is running pihole in a docker container.

I yesterday manually removed `nameserver 1.1.1.1`, but today I checked it again to my surprise has the same entry of 1.1.1.1 added agian!

Comment: I suggest to read the comments on the file `etc/resolv.conf`.  Specifically *"This file is managed by man:systemd-resolved(8). Do not edit."* -- and *"Run "systemd-resolve --status" to see details about the uplink DNS servers currently in use."*

Comment: cool, I have disabled systed-resolved and set the DNS servers to IP of what I have running .

Comment: @Nmath `systemd-resolve` returns 1.1.1.1 & 1.0.0.1, but where are they coming from? There is nothing in the config files, resolv.conf, dhcp, netplan...